# how do I get the map scale from openlayer

Tags: openlayers

I also try another method with scaleLineI have a map object:

```
_map=new Map(..)
_map.addControl(new Openlayers.Control.ScaleLine())
```

but it shows 5000000km, is it a way to show it like 1:5M on the map.
Please any helps!
thx

Answer (score 0):

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242424/how-to-get-map-units-to-find-current-scale-in-openlayers check this to get current scale of the map. Then you can create the string as "1:5M" and use javascript to update text of the scaleline divs. Register zoomend and moveend events to the map and change the inner text of the divs inside scaleline div.

```
map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(){ 
var scale= document.getElementsByClassName("olControlScaleLineTop") [0].innerHTML ;
if(!scale.includes(":"))
{
  scale = "1 : " + scale;
}
else 
{
     scale = scale.split(":")[1];
     scale = "1 : " + scale;
}
document.getElementsByClassName("olControlScaleLineTop")[0].innerHTML = scale;
});
```

Comment: Please could you explain " use update method of ScaleLine to change the label" in detail?